# View dynamic nested list in table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am new at MVC and need help.
In a view I display table, created dynamically by running over foreach loop of List.
in this table I want to display another table of List that can be shown by clicking a button.

for example:

Model1:

```
int id;
string Name;
```

Model2:

```
int title;
List<Model1> listModel1;
```

I have list of Model2 to display in table by `foreach` loop,

TITLE------LIST MODEL 1

aa---------- showListButton

bb----------  showListButton

`showListButton` will show and hide `List<Model1>` by clicking

ID------NAME

11---------- abc

22----------  efg

33----------  lmn

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Just render a table into any  element of table element. Like:

```
<table>
   <th>
      //tr
   </th>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <table>
         </table>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <table>
         </table>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I understand this is meant more or less as pseudo code, but please either make it _look_ like pseudo code, or turn it into correct HTML.